# How to connect master and slaves in Apache-Spark? (Standalone Mode)

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using [Spark Standalone Mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) tutorial page to install Spark in Standalone mode.

1- I have started a master by:

```
./sbin/start-master.sh
```

2- I have started a worker by:

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://ubuntu:7077
```

Note: `spark://ubuntu:7077` is my master name, which I can see it in `Master-WebUI`.

**Problem:** By second command, a worker started successfully. But it couldn't associate with master. It tries repeatedly and then give this message:

```
15/02/08 11:30:04 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable    remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntu:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: ubuntu/127.0.1.1:7077
15/02/08 11:30:04 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef: Message [org.apache.spark.deploy.DeployMessages$RegisterWorker] from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/user/Worker#-1296628173] to Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters] was not delivered. [20] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
15/02/08 11:31:15 ERROR Worker: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What's your spark-env.sh configuration? Have you added slaves ip's to the slaves file?

Comment: After starting worker, I added it's IP in slaves file in Master System. but I don't know about spark-env.sh ! In the tutorial page wasn't anything about it.

Comment: In the spark-env.sh I can see some variables like SPARK_MASTER_IP. I must set it with "ubuntu IP" that my master is installed on it?

Comment: Take a look at http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/connectivity_issues.html, which might have some tips for troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually start from [spark-env.sh](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/spark-env.sh.template) template. And I set, properties that I need. For simple cluster you need:

- SPARK_MASTER_IP

Then, create a file called "slaves" in the same directory as spark-env.sh and slaves ip's (one per line). Assure you reach all slaves through ssh.

Finally, **copy this configuration** in every machine of your cluster. Then start the entire cluster executing start-all.sh script and try spark-shell to check your configuration.

```
> sbin/start-all.sh
> bin/spark-shell
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have SPARK_MASTER_IP=192.168.84.128 in my spark-env.sh file and 192.168.84.129 in my slaves file. I copy these two files to the worker and master's conf folder. but when I execute ./start-all.sh in my master system I receive this error:


starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/omid/Programs/spark-1.2.0/sbin/../logs/spark-omid-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-ubuntu.out
192.168.84.129: ssh: connect to host 192.168.84.129 port 22: Connection refused

Comment: I can ping 192.168.84.129 from Master system. Isn't it sufficient? What is about ssh connection?

Comment: No, machines must be able to connect through ssh without keys. Install open-ssh, generate ssh keys (private and public) and add them to the authorized_keys for all of them.

Comment: Oh, Thanks very much. I can see my workers in my master WebUI. It's great.

Comment: Is it necessary that workers need to be started in their respective machines manually?

Comment: No, it's not necessary. ./start-all.sh script will start master and then workers. Check out the script https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sbin/start-all.sh

Comment: Today (I'm on spark 2.2.0) SPARK_MASTER_IP is deprecated, use SPARK_MASTER_HOST instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="You-IP" #to set the IP address Spark binds to on this node` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using spark 2.4.7 in standalone mode, I've created a passwordless ssh key using ssh-keygen, but still got asked for worker password when starting the cluster.

What I did was follow the instructions here
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/

This line solved the problem:
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server-ip