# Spark job throws error (spark node heartbeat error)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Spark 2.0 with 2 nodes cluster (windows machines and disabled firewall). I am running a socket program and I get the following error:

```
16/10/12 12:10:41 WARN NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(2,[Lscala.Tuple2;@1ee84de,BlockManagerId(2, IP1, 2726))] in 1 attempts
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:518)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1857)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:547)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:81)
```

I have set the value `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` to 30.  Still i am getting the error.

My environment :

Server 1 : 
I am starting the master by `spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master` 
I am starting the worker by `spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://server1:7077`

Server 2 (ip2) : 
I am starting the worker by `spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://172.16.2.95:7077`

Driver is in Server 1 : `spark-submit --master spark://server1:7077  --num-executors 2  --executor-cores 1  C:\sparkpoc\streamexample.py`

Nodes : [image]

Can any one help me ?

Comment: are you able to see the worker nodes when you open Spark UI?

Comment: Yes i can see it @amit_kumar

Comment: @amit_kumar, Added the screenshot

Comment: This type of error is nearly always due to a memory issue. You need to dig into the logs on the dying executor to learn more. If the logs aren't telling you much, look at the DAG and find the stage that's causing the problem. Once the stage is isolated, you can experiment with repartitioning data, and if that still doesn't solve the problem, I usually collect samples of the data and visually inspect it. It always leads me to the solution. Happy hunting :)

Comment: What are you doing in streamexample.py? How big is dataset? Is this problem with this particular application or cluster?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt, When i run the same application with only one node. (server1) it is working fine and i am getting the output

Comment: @amit_kumar, I am using stateful stram in streamexample.py. Which works fine in a single node. When i run it on mutiple node i am getting the above error

Comment: It is weird. You have configuration issue. can you paste what is in your spark-env.sh

Comment: @amit_kumar, I am using windows servers and i did not do anything in spark-env.sh

Comment: and what is in slaves file.

Comment: @amit_kumar, I can see localhost in slaves.template

Comment: you have to mention IP of all the slaves i.e. worker nodes. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28399360/2784721

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the executor failed to send a heartbeat message to the driver within the expected time frame. The timeout is controlled by the `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` configuration parameter.

To solve this error, you can try increasing the value of `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` to a higher value than the current one. You can set this configuration parameter in the Spark configuration file or by passing it as a command-line argument when starting the Spark application.
**spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 60s**